# Java program with thread will not exit

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, debugging, terminal

I am writing a Java program using openjdk 1.8 on Linux Mint 19.

My program spawns a thread with a runnable.

When I run the program from the command line , the program never exits back to the command prompt after completion.

In Visual Studio code though, it does properly exit when I use the debugger. 
When I connect the debugger and step through the code, after the run() method completes, the thread exit() method is being called, and then the program exits.

But from the terminal on Linux Mint, the program never exits. It is hard for me to determine what is causing this, since when I debug it, it always works.

The VSCode java debugger extension by Microsoft, which I am using, is configured and confirmed to be pointed to the same jdk version as is configured on my command line environment.

What could be causing this discrepancy between the vscode java debugger environment, and my command line environment.

Here is the code that spawns the thread:

```
public void play() {

    mState = State.STARTING;

    thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            mPlayer.open();
            boolean started = false;

            mState = BeatMachine.State.STARTED;

            boolean wasNextBufferPlayed = true;
            int end = 0;

            while (mState == BeatMachine.State.STARTED && !areAllTracksComplete()) {

                if (wasNextBufferPlayed) {
                    // calculate how much audio we can write and make sure it is an even frame (end % channels == 0)
                    end = mPlayer.availableFrames() * mPlayer.getChannels();
                    wasNextBufferPlayed = false;

                    for (int i = 0; i < mTracks.size(); i++) {
                        // get the next buffer of audio from the current track
                        mTracks.get(i).nextBuffer(mMixerBuffer , end);

                        // if it is the first track, overwrite the buffer,
                        // otherwise mix the buffer
                        for (int j = 0; j < end; j++) {
                            if (i == 0) // maybe this if could be optimized out of this loop
                                mMasterBuffer[j] = mMixerBuffer[j];
                            else
                                mMasterBuffer[j] += mMixerBuffer[j];
                        }
                        wasNextBufferPlayed = false;
                    }
                }

                wasNextBufferPlayed = mPlayer.play(mMasterBuffer , end);

                // the buffer is completely full (could FloatAudioPlayer potentially have autostart behavior)
                if (!started && mPlayer.availableFrames() == 0) {
                    mPlayer.start();
                    started = true;
                }
            }
            mPlayer.close();
            mState = BeatMachine.State.STOPPED; 
            System.out.println("This line prints in all scenarios");
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the Java code?

Comment: More context needed: What is causing the thread exit() method to be called? Is there a GUI like a JFrame involved?

Comment: Thread exit is always called after the run method exits.Nothing is "forcing" exit to be called.

Comment: What is 'the thread `exit()` method'?